# Java(Android): create ServerSocket on LocalPort used for another Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, hole-punching

I'm a little stumped and probably because I don't know how to search for this properly (I've tried many different keywords). Anyway, I'm attempting a variation of TCP hole punching(with a rendezvous server). I have created a TCP socket to the server and closed it without throwing any exceptions. But when I attempt to create a ServerSocket on the localport of the original socket it fails with IOException.

```
private static int LOCALPORT = 0;
private static String TARGETIP = "88.888.88.888";
private static int TARGETPORT = 8888;
try{
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(TARGETIP);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, TARGETPORT);
    LOCALPORT = socket.getLocalPort();
    socket.close();
    ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(LOCALPORT);
    Socket skt = sSocket.accept();
}
catch (IOException e){
}
```

I just cannot wrap my head around why I cannot close the socket and open a serversocket on the same port.

**UPDATE: from logcat**

```
java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

Comment: Fails with what IOException?

Comment: Please tell me how to find out what IOException is given, and i'll be happy to supply it here. I'm not a very experienced programmer. I just know that the catch above executes and thus it's an IOException.

Comment: In the catch block add a log line whicht prints `e.getMessage()`. Also add a line `e.printStackTrace();` And then look in the logcat and post here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I have solved my own problem thanks to greenapps and some additional searching online. Instead of closing the original socket, you need to set it to reuse instead! So simple, wow.

```
private static int LOCALPORT = 0;
private static String TARGETIP = "88.888.88.888";
private static int TARGETPORT = 8888;
try{
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(TARGETIP);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, TARGETPORT);
    LOCALPORT = socket.getLocalPort();
    //socket.close();
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(LOCALPORT);
    Socket skt = sSocket.accept();
    sSocket.close();
}
catch (IOException e){
    e.getMessage();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No. That doesn't solve anything. 'socket' is already bound when you call setReuseAddress(), which therefore does nothing.

Comment: Hey buddy, did you try to run the code? If you did, you'll see that it no longer throws an exception and I can create the ServerSocket. Please see the link where YOU also posted on (albeit you did not provide anything helpful there either) which contained the answer: [oracle forum](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1149986?start=0&tstart=0). Thanks for downvoting without knowing what you're talking about!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, TARGETPORT);` throws the `IOException`. Because the IP Address you are using is invalid. Otherwise this code should work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however there is no issue creating the socket. My issue is with the ServerSocket creation. I put a dummy IP in there so I wouldn't have my actual public IP listed on here :)

Comment: @user2981258 Unless you answer my question above your question is liable to closure due to insufficient information.

Comment: @EJP No need to be rude, I was trying to figure out how to answer your question(to no avail) but could answer this one immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an `IOException` trying to listen on the just retrieved local port:

```
 bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)
```

That should be in my opinion:

```
 port already in use
```

Why that port is not released i don't know. Would there be a possibility to unbind it?

Comment: You were right! :) Any ideas on how I would unbind the socket?